# Out of Memory exception @ 50Mb memory usage

Tags: c++, .net

I am working on a class using ADO.NET (database), I am currently simulating inputing lots of rows into my database. My function is the following one :

```
void CDatabaseAccess::AjouterEchantillon(double tension, double intensite)
{
    OleDbCommand^ cmd = gcnew OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO echantillons (id_course, tension, intensite) VALUES ('"+CDatabaseAccess::GetLastIdCourse()+"', '"+tension+"', '"+intensite+"')", conn);
    OleDbDataReader^ cmdReader = cmd->ExecuteReader();
    delete cmd;
    delete cmdReader;
}
```

I am facing a problem when I try to call this function in this `for` loop :

```
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                database->AjouterEchantillon(rDouble, j);
                Threading::Thread::Sleep(10);
            }
```

My problem is the following : the memory keep raising until it crashes when my app is around 50Mb memory usage. It looks like the garbage collector is not working, or my `cmdReader` isn't deleted and stays in memory. I'd like to know what could cause this.

Comment: These are disposable objects, if you don't delete them and the GC doesn't run often enough then you can certainly run out of *unmanaged* resources.  Use the `delete` operator or stack semantics.

Comment: I already tried to use `delete cmd` and `delete cmdReader` at the end of my function, but this doesn't change anything. The program keeps crashing

Comment: Well, nice job of posting repro code.  If you already know that calling delete is required then intentionally omitting it from your snippet is a dumb thing to do and you'll never get a usable answer.

Comment: Alright I added it, but as I said, calling `delete` doesn't change anything.

Comment: 50MB shouldn't be enough to cause an out-of-memory error; how did you obtain that number?

Comment: You're right, that's why I don't understand my problem. I get that number in the task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so today I just tried to force garbage collection using the .NET method `GC::Collect()` at the end of my method and it worked perfectly.

Comment: This confirms the theory that you are not disposing the objects promptly and instead are relying on GC scavenging and finalizing them for you.

Comment: Do you think my method is the right thing to do in order to make this work ? Or is there a problem before all this ?